# Linear algebra, prove that this operator is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

So Im stuck with this one, i know there are condition to be satisfied but i just don't get it,
so if you're willing, please do
$A:\Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$, 
$Ax=x_2e_1+(x_1-3x_2)e_2+5x_3e_3$, where $x,e_1,e_2,e_3$ are vectors

Comment: It would be much easier to read if you formatted your question with mathjax.

Comment: What is the definition of linear? Start with that. For starters: try to calculate `A(x+y)` and see if you can verify that it is the same as `Ax+Ay`

Comment: all vectorized!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to check is that $A(x+y)=A(x)+A(y)$, $A(\lambda x) =\lambda A(x)$. Since $A$ is acting on the components of a vector only by linear operations, which are multiplication by a constant and addition, it is indeed linear. For example \begin{equation}\begin{split}A(x+y)&= (x_2+y_2) e_1 +(x_1+y_1-3(x_2+y_2))e_2+5(x_3+y_3)e_3\\&= x_2 e_1+(x_1-3x_2)e_2+5x_3 e_3+y_2 e_1+(y_1-3y_2)e_2+5y_3 e_3 =A(x)+A(y)\end{split}\end{equation}

Comment: my god, this is really abstract for me :D
so even if it is only x in question, i have to go with A(x+y)=Ax+Ay

Comment: Ask if you need help on something in particular. It might be easier if you write how $A$ acts on a vector in vector form:$A (x_1,x_2, x_3) = (x_2,x_1-3 x_2,5 x_3 )$. I wanted to write vectors as columns but could not have it working, sorry!

Comment: ... i did it :)

Comment: Congrats! How? I tried \begin{array} but it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you must show:

- Given $x,y\in\Bbb R^3,$ we have $A(x+y)=A(x)+A(y).$
- Given $x\in\Bbb R^3$ and $c\in\Bbb R,$ we have $A(cx)=cA(x).$

The big thing to keep in mind is that for any $v\in\Bbb R^3,$ we can write $v$ *uniquely* in the form $v_1e_1+v_2e_2+v_3e_3$ for some $v_1,v_2,v_3\in\Bbb R.$

Comment: super excellent answer +1

Answer (score 1):

*If* $A$ is linear, then it coincides with the multiplication by a matrix, precisely the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}Ae_1 & Ae_2 & Ae_3\end{bmatrix}
$$
(where I specify the matrix by its columns). Since
$$
Ae_1=e_2,\quad
Ae_2=e_1-3e_2,\quad
Ae_3=5e_3
$$
the matrix should be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2 \\
x_1-3x_2 \\
5x_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
x_2e_1+(x_1-3x_2)e_2+5e_3=Ax.
$$
Therefore $A$ is the multiplication by a matrix, so it is linear.

Comment: i was thinking of doing something like that but i wasn't sure i could do it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you would like, you can use the language of matrices, to
map ${\Bbb{R}}^3\to {\Bbb{R}}^3$ linearly, you can use matrix's multiplicaction:
$$
x=
\left(\!\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{array}\!\right)
\longrightarrow
Ax=\left(\!\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&-3&0\\
0&0&-5
\end{array}\!\right)
\left(\!\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{array}\!\right).
$$

With this device is a routine to check $A(x+y)=Ax+Ay $ and $A(cx)=cAx$ that you need to grasp.

Check that  $Ax+Ay=A(x+y)$ all vectorized amounts to this:

$$
Ax+Ay=
\left(\!\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&-3&0\\
0&0&-5
\end{array}\!\right)
\left(\!\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{array}\!\right)
+
\left(\!\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&-3&0\\
0&0&-5
\end{array}\!\right)
\left(\!\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{array}\!\right)
$$

$$
=
\left(\!\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&-3&0\\
0&0&-5
\end{array}\!\right)
\left(
\left(\!\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{array}\!\right)
+
\left(\!\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{array}\!\right)
\right)
$$

$$
=
\left(\!\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&-3&0\\
0&0&-5
\end{array}\!\right)
\left(\!\begin{array}{c}
x_1+y_1\\
x_2+y_2\\
x_3+y_3
\end{array}\!\right)
$$

$$
=A(x+y)
$$

Comment: so with this i wouldn't need y1 y2 y3 to prove that it's linear, unlike in answer above right?
and thanks!

Comment: mmmh... you gonna needed in the checking of $A(x+y)=Ax+Ay$... the vantage in my approach is that you don't get confused by the object's description... you gotta use the matrix multiplication's properties